# Nminimize output of ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, event-detection

I want to minimize the time a family of ODEs vanishes.
To do so, I'm using WhenEvent to extract the vanishing time and put the result inside Nminimize:

```
f=ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] + s x[t] == 0, x[0] == x'[0] == 1, WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, end = t; "StopIntegration"]}, {x,end}, {t,\[Infinity]}, {s}]
NMinimize[{f[r][[2]], 0 < r < 1}, r]
```

I get the warning:

```
Part::partw: Part 2 of ParametricFunction[1,Internal`Bag[<1>],0,1,{{s$186129},System`Utilities`HashTable[<2>],{},{},{1},{Automatic,0,0},{0}},{NDSolve`base$186136,NDSolve`NDSolveParametricFunction[0,{ParametricNDSolveValue,Internal`Bag[<2>],None,ParametricNDSolveValue},{{{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}},{0,{Slot[<<1>>]&,Slot[<<1>>]&,Slot[<<1>>]&},{0,{t$186130}},{{x},{x},{x}}},None,{{{s$186129},System`Utilities`HashTable[<2>],{},{},{1},{Automatic,0,0},{0}},{Automatic},None,{}}},{x,1.50661},{{Times[<<2>>]+(<<1>>^(<<1>>))[<<1>>]==0,x[0]==1,(x^\[Prime])[0]==1},{},{},{},{WhenEvent[x[<<1>>]==0,Set[<<2>>];StopIntegration]}},{{\[Infinity]}},{Automatic,Automatic,MachinePrecision,Automatic,Automatic,Automatic,Automatic,None,None,Automatic,<<17>>},{Cache->True,CacheTableLength->19,CacheTableWidth->7,CacheKeyMaxBytes->1000000,CacheResultMaxBytes->1000000,KeyComparison->None,ResultComparison->LessEqual},{},All]}][r] does not exist.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem you're facing is related to the [order of evaluation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html). One possible solution which mentioned in the `NMinimize`s Possible Issues is to define an intermediary function like `ClearAll[temp]; temp[n_?NumericQ] := f[n][[2]];` and use that like `NMinimize[{temp[r], 0 < r < 1}, r]` which outputs `{2.35619, {r -> 0.99... }}`. (Version 13.2)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `f[r][[2]]` with `Indexed[f[r], 2]`.

```
f = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] + s x[t] == 0, x[0] == x'[0] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[x[t] == 0, end = t; "StopIntegration"]}, {x, 
   end}, {t, ∞}, {s}]
NMinimize[{Indexed[f[r], 2], 0 < r < 1}, r]
```

> `{2.35619, {r -> 1.}}`

Comment: Yes, `Indexed` is perfect for these kinds of problems